# Creating small image file png's showing tabular data from Excel or other spreadsheet

Tags: excel, png, spreadsheet

On: Creating small image file png's showing tabular data

We sometimes need to show data online. There are a couple of popular ways of doing this:

1. HTML table
2. JSON/Xml or other and using some method to display
3. Creating an image

In this case we need to (or prefer to) create PNG images. The method we use now is to create it in Excel and export it to PNG.

The problem is that we have seen is that these images are not really optimized. And don't look nice when zoomed in. Or on different displays.

**Question:** now what would be the best way of exporting table/tabular data from program X where we can store it (like Excel) to a clean and neat image format lik epNG that is safe for the web?

Advice and ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick and good solution for your need. It is [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)
It renders any web page or local html file and converts it image or pdf. Result is satisfactory. It has windows, linux, bsd, os x ports.

> What is it?
>
> wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltoimage are open source (LGPLv3) command line tools to render HTML into PDF and various image formats using the Qt WebKit rendering engine. These run entirely "headless" and do not require a display or display service.
>
> There is also a C library, if you're into that kind of thing.

Usage is as easy as like this:

`wkhtmltoimage.exe http://www.google.com output.png`

**Note:** You can set the quality of the image from command line and have very small sized images with additional command line options.

---

For example this code becomes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

this image (size 5.16 KB with --quality 80)
[image: 5.16 KB png file]

And this becomes
`wkhtmltoimage.exe --quality 80 https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en output.png`

this (size 32.7 KB)
[image]